# Why below two hive sql having different result?

Tags: hive, hiveql

hive version is 2.1.0

hql 1:

```
hive> select day, datediff(day, '2017-01-01') from mall_stat_daily where day='2017-11-13';

result:
2017-11-13      315
```

hql2:

```
hive> select day, datediff('2017-11-13', '2017-01-01') from mall_stat_daily where day='2017-11-13';

result:
2017-11-13      316
```

why these having different result?
I also test these sqls in mysql and get the same result '316'.

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in 2.0.0 as the date formatter uses UTC timezone when parsing dates from the string. This would work correctly when both parameters are of string type, but when one of the parameters is of string type and the other is date/timestamp type it gives incorrect results because the date/timestamp value will have milliseconds result based on the date for the local timezone. 
This was fixed in 2.3 release.https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15338

Hope this helps.